# Prototype.js - $(...).next is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I try to convert my code from jQuery to prototype.js. I execute the following code, but get `$(...).next is not a function`

```
var editorCounter = 0;
var newEditorIds = [];

$$(".input-text.mceEditor").each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    var tagName = next.prop("tagName");

    if (typeof(tagName) == "undefined") {
        var newId = "newEditor_" + editorCounter;
        $(this).attr("id", newId);
        newEditorIds.push(newId);
        editorCounter++;
    }
});

newEditorIds.each(function(name, index) {
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, name);
});
```

It is not fully converted to prototype.js. I still have to figure out the equivalents for `prop()` and `attr()`.
I don't understand what I did wrong so far though, since I informed myself on [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_element_next.htm) and it should work.

---

**Original working jQuery Code:**

```
var editorCounter = 0;
var newEditorIds = [];

jQuery(".input-text.mceEditor").each(function() {
    var next = jQuery(this).next();
    var tagName = next.prop("tagName");

    if (typeof(tagName) == "undefined") {
        var newId = "newEditor_" + editorCounter;
        jQuery(this).attr("id", newId);
        newEditorIds.push(newId);
        editorCounter++;
    }
});

jQuery.each(newEditorIds, function(i, v) {
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, v);
});
```

Comment: you mean to say that Original jQuery Code:is working fine but prototype.js is not working?

Comment: Yes exactly @NegiRox

Comment: are you using another library on same page?

Comment: try $$(this).next();

Comment: I only use prototype.js on this page.

Comment: You are using ``$$(".input-text.mceEditor")`` but ``$(this)``. There seems to be an inconsistency there

Comment: as we all know Jquery is generally shortend by $ but in your code i can see $$ .

Comment: Im not sure yet when to use $$ an when $ is expected.

Comment: `$$` acts as `querySelectorAll` - takes a selector and gives an `Array`. `$` acts as `getElementById` - takes an ID and gives an `Element`.

Comment: BTW, `writeAttribute` is a more powerful version of plain vanilla `setAttribute`. There is no equivalent to `prop` - just use properties directly on `Element` objects. i.e. instead of `$(element).prop('checked', true)` just say `element.checked = true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.each` that you are using does not set `this`. You are supposed to provide an argument in the callback function to receive the element. Thus:

```
$$(".input-text.mceEditor").each(function(element) {
    var next = element.next();
```

(You may use `$(element)`, but it doesn't do anything except when you don't know whether `element` is an ID or an `Element`. Prototype uses monkey-patching, not wrapping, so you can use a bare `Element` directly.)

---

**Converted code:**

```
var editorCounter = 0;
var newEditorIds = [];

$$(".input-text.mceEditor").each(function(element) {
    var next = element.next();

    if (typeof(next) == "undefined") {
        var newId = "newEditor_" + editorCounter;
        element.id = newId;
        newEditorIds.push(newId);
        editorCounter++;
    }
});

newEditorIds.each(function(name, index) {
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, name);
});
```

Comment: The corrected code supplied by @Black. (Sorry for the rollback, I misread something and thought it was incorrect for a second, and rolled back impulsively.)